# Cabal update fails with 404 error trying to access a non existing file when compiling Apache Thrift

Tags: haskell, thrift, cabal, haskell-stack, stackage

I'm trying to install [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org) on my system, which performs a `cabal update` command. This command fails with the following message:

```
Downloading the latest package list from stackage cabal: Failed to download
http://www.stackage.org/stackage/7ae494fec2db3161dfb8e64677149285857478e0/00-index.tar.gz
: ErrorMisc "Error HTTP code: 404"
```

I normally use `stack` and I never had to do a `cabal update` manually. I don't know if the interaction between `cabal` and `stack` is a problem here.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

*EDIT*: Looking at my `~/.cabal/config~ I see the following entry:

```
remote-repo: stackage:http://www.stackage.org/stackage/7ae494fec2db3161dfb8e64677149285857478e0
```

So it seems that line is the culprit, but I don't know whether `stack` could have changed this for a good reason.

Comment: It seems that initially `remote-repo` referencing particular stackage
snapshot
[would use a hash of some sort]( https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/08/announcing-stackage-server) (7ae494fec2db3161dfb8e64677149285857478e0)
I believe that naming convention has been discontinued and
snapshots
[are now referenced by name](https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.14/cabal.config?global=true)